# Constructores opcionales y obligatorios

Tags: java, poo, constructor

soy nuevo en esto de POO y en un ejercicio me dicen lo siguiente:

*El atributo titular será obligatorio y la cantidad es opcional. Crea dos constructores que cumpla lo anterior*

He estado buscando sobre cómo hacer constructores que cumplan con esas condiciones y no encuentro nada que hable de eso, ayuda

Comment: En Java hay varios patrones para realizar lo que plantea tu ejercicio. [Revisa este artículo](http://dolszewski.com/java/java-optional-parameters/) y decide el que mejor te convenga.

Comment: Si estás empezando quizá lo que te están pidiendo que uses son constructores sobrecargados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo que te piden es sobrecargar el constructor de tu clase, este se realiza cuando quieres instanciar la clase de distintas maneras, en tu caso con datos opcionales, un ejemplo:

Tengo la clase Direccion.java

```
public class Direccion {

    private String calle;
    private int numero;

    public Direccion(String calle, int numero) {
        this.calle = calle;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    //getters y setters...
}
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta en esta clase la única manera de instanciar es indicando ambos valores (calle y número) es decir: `Direccion direccion = new Direccion("Avenida Alemania", 1500);`, en caso de que quieras que uno de los campos de dicha clase sea opcional, como por ejemplo el número, deberíamos usar la sobrecarga de constructor, esto se logra creando otro constructor con distintos parámetros, en este caso solo con la dirección, nuestra clases quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Direccion {

    private String calle;
    private int numero;

    public Direccion(String calle, int numero) {
        this.calle = calle;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public Direccion(String calle) {
        this.calle = calle;
        this.numero = 0;
    }

    //getters y setters...
}
```

con esta sobrecarga de constructor ahora podremos instanciar la clase de dos formas:

```
Direccion direccion = new Direccion("Avenida Alemania", 1500);
```

o tambien con solo la calle:

```
Direccion direccion = new Direccion("Avenida Alemania");
```

De la segunda forma no indicamos el valor número de la clase, no obstante la instanciaremos de igual manera, en este caso tomaría el valor 0 por defecto ya que fue el que le indicamos en el constructor, es decir podremos indicar el valor que nosotros queramos o no indicar nada, que en el caso de un valor int tomara el valor por defecto que es 0.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero esto no es cierto: *en esta clase la única manera de instanciar es indicando ambos valores (calle y número) es decir: `Direccion direccion = new Direccion("Avenida Alemania", 1500);`* Las clases siempre admiten el constructor por defecto, de modo que puedes instanciar siempre una clase de este modo:  `LaClase mClase = new LaClase();`, así que esta forma de instanciar es posible: `Direccion direccion = new Direccion();`  aun si no tienes definido ningún constructor de forma explícita.

Comment: @A.Cedano el constructor vacío sólo es agregado por el compilador cuando no se ha definido otro en su lugar. Por lo cual no sería posible instanciar `new Direccion()` pues ya existe uno que evita que se autogenere el constructor vacío

Comment: @EduardoJiménez no, no es así. Todas las clases tienen un constructor por defecto sin parámetros. Puedes probarlo si quieres.

Comment: Hmm, creo que entendemos del mismo texto algo distinto, pues yo leo que **"*en esta clase la única manera de instanciar es indicando ambos valores (calle y número)*"** como si al referirse a "esta clase" se refiere a la que tiene el constructor `public Direccion(String calle, int numero)`, por lo cual yo no veo problemas en lo que escribió. Pues es verdad que no puede instanciar esa clase en específico con algo diferente a sus 2 argumentos

Comment: @EduardoJiménez la clase es `Direccion`, y puede ser instanciada de dos maneras: 1. Como un objeto sin atributos con `new Dirección()` 2. Como un objeto con dos atributos con `new Dirección("una calle", 1)` (me refiero a lo explicado con respecto al primer bloque de código en la respuesta). Simplemente lo afirmado ahí puede hacer pensar que el constructor por defecto no puede usarse cuando defines un constructor con parámetros, lo cual es falso. Puedes probar a crear una clase según el 1er modelo y luego intentar crear una instancia con `new Dirección()` y verás que funciona.

Comment: No @A.Cedano, el constructor por defecto lo agrega el compilador SOLO cuando no se ha declarado ningún constructor en la clase. Esto quiere decir que si intentas instanciar la clase `Direccion` de la siguiente manera: `new Direccion()`, tendrás un error de compilación puesto que no se encontrará un constructor cuya lista de parámetros councida con la especificada (sin parámetros).

Comment: @A.Cedano, lo anterior lo deja claro la especificación del lenguaje. ***8.8.9. Default Constructor: If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared.***

Comment: @A.Cedano me tome la molestia de hacer el ejercicio que dices, y estás equivocado, el compilador agrega un constructor sin parámetros solo cuando no tiene ninguno declarado [Ejemplo](https://prnt.sc/1qah3e1)

Comment: @Fernando-N tienes razón, estaba errado en ese punto. El constructor por defecto se invoca cuando no hay ningún constructor. Gracias por la aclaración.